# join array with a condition - Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I have a matrix with "seccion" keys and I want to join it by "seccion". Help me here I leave an example.
I am already grateful for your support. Sorry for my English

At the beginning I have this then try to join them:

```
{0: {seccion: "0", stitulo: "titulo_test1"}, 
 1: {seccion: "0", ssub: "sub_test1"},
 2: {seccion: "1", stitulo: "titulo_test2"},
 3: {seccion: "1", ssub: "sub_test2"}
}
```

What I do is go through all the objects with an assigned class, but the "i" counter overwrites them:

```
var secciones={};
$('#formSecciones').find('.secc').each(function(i,s) {
    secciones[`$(s).closest('.dd-item').attr('data-id')] = {};
    secciones[`$(s).closest('.dd-item').attr('data-id')][i] = {};
    secciones[`$(s).closest('.dd-item').attr('data-id')][i][s.name] = s.value;
});
```

Result:

```
{0:{1:{ssub: "sub_test1"}},
 1:{3:{ssub: "sub_test2"}}
}
```

This is what I want to get:

```
{0: {ssub: "sub_test1", stitulo: "titulo_test1"},
 1: {stitulo: "titulo_test2", ssub: "sub_test2"}
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't operating on the object, it's operating on DOM elements.

Comment: You have a bunch of unmatched backticks.

Comment: Treating an object like an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only create a new object if the object doesn't already exist at that key.

Also, you don't want nested arrays, so you don't need `[i]` in the target of the assignment.

```
var secciones={};
$('#formSecciones').find('.secc').each(function(i,s) {
    var id = $(s).closest('.dd-item').attr('data-id');
    if (!secciones[id]) {
        secciones[id] = {};
    }
    secciones[id][s.name] = s.value;
});
```

Comment: thank you very much I am very grateful, I had already tried something similar but I do not remember what was wrong.